# Should I use is_admin() inside 'admin_init' hook callback

Tags: admin

I'm adding an action witht he following line:

`add_action( 'admin_init', 'fb_init_scripts');`

And my function looks like this:

```
  function fb_init_scripts() {
    //Only use these scripts in admin interface
    if (is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7/jquery-ui.min.js',array('jquery'));
    }
  }
```

In this instance, is it pointless to use `is_admin()` to controll if I'm in admin panel, since I'm running this function in `admin_init` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, pointless.

`admin_init` only fires in admin area (and couple more files related to AJAX functionality) so additional `is_admin()` check is not necessary.

It often comes up in examples for hooks that fire both on front-end and admin area.

Answer (score 5):

As Rarst said it's redundant. The ajax interface happens to be in the admin area for reasons related to authentication, and WP considers it to be part of the admin area -- including when it technically isn't.

A good "trick", that said, is to wrap applicable add_action() calls in an `if` block:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
  add_action('admin_init', 'foo');
}
```

Doing so avoids polluting the `$wp_filter` global on the front end.

Better yet, create a separate file with admin-related code, and only include it in the admin area (or when needed, using the `'load-$pagehook'` action). You can see an example of how this is done here:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sem-external-links/